# How to append to /etc/hosts file from the termimal?

Tags: linux, shell, hosts

I'm trying to append to the /etc/hosts file from the termimal:

```
sudo echo -e "127.0.0.1      localhost-myproject" >> /etc/hosts
```

Even though I'm doing as sudo, it won't let me. I get permission denied:

```
bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
```

I've looked at a couple other posts and they instruct like this. But I'm getting this error. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo -e "127.0.0.1 localhost-myproject" >> /etc/hosts'

Comment: worked on ubuntu 16